# Add-AppDevPackage.ps1 asking for Name[0] parameter

Tags: windows-8, windows-store-apps

I created a windows 8 app package following the instructions at:

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/patricka/archive/2012/11/05/how-do-i-deploy-a-windows-8-app-to-another-device-for-testing.aspx

However, when I run Add-AppDevPackage.ps1 on my hp stream 7, as administrator:

.\Add-AppDevPackage.ps1

I am being asked for a parameter value:

Name[0]:

I just enter anything such as "test", then I get another prompt:

Name[1]:

Then I just press enter.  Now I get an error:

```
Cannot overwrite variable false because it is read-only or constant.
At C:\temp1234\AppPackages\App3_1.0.0.0_AnyCPU_Debug_Test\Add-AppDevPackage.ps1:30 char:36
+ [switch]$GetDeveloperLicense = $false,
+ CategoryInfo :WriteError (false:String) [], SessionStateUnauthorizedAccessException
+FullyQualifiedErrorId : VariableNotWriteable

Found Package:  C:\temp1234\AppPackages\App3_1.0.0.0_AnyCPU_Debug_Test\App3_1.0.0.0_AnyCPU_Debug.appx
Found Certificate: C:\temp1234\AppPackages\App3_1.0.0.0_AnyCPU_Debug_Test\App3_1.0.0.0_AnyCPU_Debug.cer

Before installing this app, you need to do the following:
 - Acquire a developer license
 - Install the signing certificate
Error: Could not acquire a developer license.  For more information, see http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?Li..
Press Enter to continue...:
```

My question is what is it asking for when it prompts for Name[0] ?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I cant believe no one from Microsoft caught this one!  After wrestling with this for days, I finally figured the problem.  When I created the AppPackage, I had "Debug" selected from the dropdown in visual studio 2013.  I selected "Release", then recreated the package, rolled that out to a folder on the hp stream again and just right clicked on the ps1 file, chose "Run with powershell" and everything was smooth after that.  The certificate and app installed fine and I did not get any prompt asking for a Name parameter.